# How to get an array of attribute value from elements in a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I use a custom attribute in elements with my own class. I'm trying to return the value of custom attribute for all elements of the class.

I used jQuery to find the elements by class, and jQuery places the object in an array.

```
var tabs = $('li.tab_item');
```

Now that I'd have the objects in an array, I would like to return the value for the custom attribute for all the array's members.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var tab_attribs = $('li.tab_item').map(function () {
  return $(this).attr("custom_attribute");
}).toArray();
```

This will give you an array of the custom attribute values. Of course, you can do this more traditionally:

```
var tab_attribs = [];
$('li.tab_item').each(function () {
  tab_attribs.push( $(this).attr("custom_attribute") );
});
```

Anyway, you should probably make use of the `data-*` attributes that HTML5 provides:

```
<li class="tab_item" data-foo="some custom data">
```

and (see [jQuery `data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)):

```
$('li.tab_item').data("foo"); // -> "some custom data"
```

Comment: Thanks... both on the top worked

$('li.tab_item').data("foo"); // only returns one entry

Comment: @garyM Of course it does. You are supposed to use that in a loop, like `map()` or `each()`.

Comment: Ahh... I thought it worked like $('li.tab_item') .. returning an array. In the jQuery doc, it mentions that fact for ".attr()".  Again thanks ...

Comment: @garyM Everything in jQuery that returns a value breaks the chain. That's true for getting `.text()`, `.html()`, `.attr('xyz')` and the like. However, if a method is not returning an immediate value, like setting `.attr('xyz', 'new value')`, it returns the elements that were previously matched, i.e. an array.

Comment: just add, tab_attribs.toArray()

Comment: @Hatim is right, without toArray() you will get a jquery collection instead of an array!

Answer (score 7):

Use `.map()`:

```
 $("li.tab_item").map(function (){
    return this.getAttribute("myAttribute");
 });
```

That gives you an Array of values wrapped in a jQuery object. If you want to get the Array, call `.get()`, ie `.map(...).get()`.

By the way, you can also select the elements by attribute instead of class:

```
$("[myAttribute]")
```

This will return all elements on the page that have a `myAttribute` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple solution (ES6)**

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tab_item')).map(item => item.getAttribute('foo'));
```

**[Online demo (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/0ofcpp0k/1/)**